# Geofire + Infinite Scroll - Can it Work?

Tags: javascript, firebase, geofire

I have an app that fetches nearby locations around a user that stored in my Firebase via Geofire's lat/long coordinates.

I now want to be able to fetch more locations when the user scrolls to the bottom of the list of locations (aka inifinite scroll).

To do this, I increment the radius which in turn fetches more locations - however I'd like to avoid fetching the same locations that have already been loaded. Does Geofire support anything like this (i.e., excluding already-loaded locations in a query) or will this have to be handled through some manual processing?

Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Geofire will always return all keys that fall within the range of your Geoquery. So if you create Geoqueries for increasingly large ranges, you will get the overlapping keys.

But the keys in Geofire are quite small, usually a lot smaller than the actual objects that the keys represent. So if you ensure that you don't reload objects you've already loaded, it may still be feasible.

Answer (score 1):

You want to `diff` the new result set against what you've already got and handle only the new key/value pairs.  This can be achieved using the `array.filter` method.  So, vanilla js really.

Comment: Thanks Ron, I did come up with a vanilla solution that seems to do the trick efficiently enough. I'll post shortly

Answer (score 0):

Using a pure vanilla javascript solution, I was able to achieve only appending new locations with the following:

```
$scope.locations = ... // returned from service method
var existingKeys = []; // keep track of existing firebase keys

$scope.locations.forEach(function(location){ // Store the initial location ids
  existingKeys.push(location.id);
});

locationService.getNearby(5) // Set 3km as the new radius (was 2km)
  .then(function(moreLocations){
    moreLocations.forEach(function(newLocation){

    /** Prevents pushing duplicates into array by comparing the existing keys **/
    if(existingKeys.indexOf(newLocation.id) === -1 ){
      $scope.locations.push(newLocation);
      existingKeys.push(newLocation.id); // Append new keys to existingKeys[] 
    }
})
```

**Note** * this does *not* prevent reloading the same objects x amount of times